# Use grid file for GDA2020 in QGIS 3.12

Tags: qgis, gda2020

I am trying to add a custom crs in QGIS for GDA2020 using grid file GDA94_GDA2020_conformal.gsb. My parameter is

```
proj=utm +zone=51 +south +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +nadgrids=GDA94_GDA2020_conformal.gsb
```

My test point is
North: -21.7403935833333
East: 121.197650527778

When I press "Calculate", it just says "Error" in the result box. I checked and the file is there in C:\OSGeo4W64\share\proj

Is there anyway to know what the error is?

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded the ICSM .gsb grid files:
https://github.com/icsm-au/transformation_grids

Save these in the qgis/share/proj folder

I've found some issues with Realtime transformations with multiple web-based sources in different CRS in a single map. If I save and quit it's usually resolved once I return.